# Why do I have a null variable in my array?

Tags: php

I'm building a social media web app, and while I can successfully display posts to a feed, I also get these error messages:

```
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /opt/lampp/htdocs/social/includes/classes/User.php on line 34

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /opt/lampp/htdocs/social/includes/classes/User.php on line 37
```

These error messages repeat a number of times, and are displayed on the feed:

[image: screenshot of app with errors and posts]

Here's the code that the error messages point to:

```
public function getFirstAndLastName() {
    $username = $this->user['username']; //ERROR line 34
    $query = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    return $row['first_name'] . " " . $row['last_name']; // ERROR line 37
}
```

And here's my constructor for a user:

```
    public function __construct($con, $user){
    $this->con = $con;
    $user_details_query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user'");
    $this->user = mysqli_fetch_array($user_details_query);
}
```

The database has values for the first and last names, and they're written in the same format. Why am I getting a null value even though I'm able to post to the app?

Answer (score 0):

It's not in array (and actually notice is pretty clear about that). Your `$this->user` is null which means you need to rather check where you set it and why it did not work (or maybe you try to access it too early, before it's set?).